# Programmatic Report in Lightswitch

Tags: c#, report, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is it possible to create a report programmatically in Light Switch?

I would like my customer to enter data and upon saving, a report is automatically generated and saved in a specific location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightswitch doesn't have built-in reporting. There are a number of options including third-party extensions,custom silverlight controls, SQL Server Reports, and integration with microsoft office. A summary of these options is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635143.aspx If your program operates in a desktop environment using office may be the easiest. I've used http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/09/22/fun-with-the-office-integration-pack-extension-for-lightswitch.aspx as a guide successfully. You can even automatically save (as an office file or a PDF) to a specific file path. As far as I know, if you are running in-browser you will not be able to automatically save the file - but there are still plenty of options.